# Merge jq output into a comma separated string

Tags: command-line, curl, json, jq

I am trying to `curl` some URL which returns a json file, then I want to parse hosts from it and create a comma separated string.

I have the first part working

```
curl -s -u "admin:admin" -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" "https://hbasecluster.net/api/v1/clusters/mycluster/services/ZOOKEEPER/components/ZOOKEEPER_SERVER" | jq -r '.host_components[].HostRoles.host_name'
```

which returns

```
zk0-mycluster.net
zk1-mycluster.net
zk2-mycluster.net
```

Now I want to join these into one string like

```
zk0-mycluster.net,zk1-mycluster.net,zk2-mycluster.net
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Do it in `jq`, but see [@Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663406/4667)  first

```
jq -r '.host_components[].HostRoles.host_name | join(",")'
```

---

No, that's wrong. This is what you need:

```
jq -r '.host_components | map(.HostRoles.host_name) | join(",")'
```

Demo:

```
jq -r '.host_components | map(.HostRoles.host_name) | join(",")' <<DATA
{"host_components":[
  {"HostRoles":{"host_name":"one"}},
  {"HostRoles":{"host_name":"two"}},
  {"HostRoles":{"host_name":"three"}}
]}
DATA
```

outputs

```
one,two,three
```

Comment: just as an alternative, should also work: `jq -r '[.host_components[].HostRoles.host_name] | join(",")'`

Comment: @webwurst just tried, it's not working in case if you're selecting multiple columns/keys. For example: `jq -r '[.host_components[].HostRoles.some_other_value, .host_components[].HostRoles.host_name] | join(",")]'`

Answer (score 34):

`paste` is the best tool to do this job:

```
your_command | paste -sd, -
```

Answer (score 17):

If what you want is CSV-formatted output from your JSON document, then you may use the `@csv` operator in `jq`.

```bsh
somecommand | jq -r '[ .host_components[].HostRoles.host_name ] | @csv'
```

This uses the same expression that you're  using in the question to pull out the data that you want, but it puts all the host names into an array.  The array is then passed through `@csv` which makes sure that that the data is properly quoted for CSV output.

You would expect to get the following output from this:

```
"zk0-mycluster.net","zk1-mycluster.net","zk2-mycluster.net"
```

Any commas, double quotes, or newlines embedded in the values would be properly quoted as expected in a CSV-formatted file.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `awk`, just print with no `newline`:

```
    <your command> | awk 'NR > 1 { printf(",") } {printf "%s",$0}'
```